# Is $\sigma(X,Y) = \sigma(X, X \cdot Y)$ for two Random Variables $X$ and $Y$?

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

Suppose we have two real random variables $X,Y$. Then clearly

\begin{equation}
\sigma(X, X \cdot Y) \subset  \sigma(X,Y) 
\end{equation}

since both $X$ and $X \cdot Y$ are $\sigma(X,Y)$-measurable and $\sigma(X, X \cdot Y)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra such that these two are measurable.

What about the other inclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other inclusion is in general false. If $X = 0$ is constant, then $\sigma(X, Y) = \sigma(Y)$, while $\sigma(X, XY) = \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$. These are different for any nonconstant random variable $Y$.